# Is this an ok clone function?

Tags: javascript

Is this an okay clone function for cloning an object recursively?

```
function clone(o)
{
    function CloneObject(inObj) 
    {
        for (i in inObj) 
        {
            if(typeof inObj[i] == 'object')
                this[i] = clone(inObj[i]);
            else
                this[i] = inObj[i];
        }
    }

    return new CloneObject(o);
}
```

Also, i found out this doesn't work with arrays. How can I clone an array?

Comment: There are plenty of threads on that topic: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+clone+object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly doesn't clone the object perfectly — the clone won't have the original's prototype, and they'll have different constructors, and if the original has any non-iterable properties, then this won't copy them — but you ask if it's "okay", and the answer to that may well be "yes": If what it does is all that you need it to do, then it's absolutely fine.

As for cloning arrays — you could check if `inObj.constructor == Array`.

Comment: actually, i found a better solution here: http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/show.dml/1725165